# Unexpected and unintuitive behaviour with Numba Prange

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

As summarised in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6933) Numba displays some very unintuitive behaviour when reducing to a slice from a prange statement.

Consider the following code below, which is a typical hot loop for parallelisation. When the result of a computation are reduced to a slice as below,

```py
@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def hot_loop():
    
    n=10000
    
    result = np.zeros((n*100), np.float32)
    for i in numba.prange(n):
        
        # Run computations
        res = np.random.rand(100,100) @ np.random.rand(100)
        
        # Store result
        result[i*100:(i+1)*100] += res
        
    return result
```

it is significantly slower than an allocated array,

```py
@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def hot_loop():
    
    n=10000
    
    result = np.zeros((n*100), np.float32)
    for i in numba.prange(n):
        
        # Run computations
        res = np.random.rand(100,100) @ np.random.rand(100)
        
        # Store allocated array
        result[i*100:(i+1)*100] += np.random.rand(100)
        
    return result
```

Results for my Intel I7 CPU are 74ms for the former, and 974 microseconds for the latter. There is no mention of this anywhere in the docs, or on other issues, but significantly impacts what you can really use prange for. I.e. why would you compute complex array based math in a prange, if you then get a huge bottleneck for saving  your results.

The issue may be that prange is not fully supported to reduce to slices in this way, however, that doesn't seem to matter for the latter case - which is confusing and non-intuitive behaviour.

Does anyone else have experience of this behaviour?

Comment: Because the second version doesn’t use res, optimizer optimizes it out, it doesn’t get calculated, thus the speed up

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, the line

```
res = np.random.rand(100,100) @ np.random.rand(100)
```

calculates variable `res` that's not used. If you delete the line, the timing is exactly the same.

It's very likely that the [LLVM compiler](https://llvm.org/) optimization pass is detecting the unused variable and deleting the code needed to evaluate it.